# "Digital Stereo" missing from PCM2901 Codec

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio

I have a USB device (Icom IC-7100) that I have successfully connected to my Ubuntu (Mint 18) box (running FLDIGI) in the past.  To work properly, I normally use the Pulse Audio volume control to select "Digital Stereo" in the configuration tab.  However, following a recent kernel update, only "Analog Stereo" is offered (the Digital options are no longer in the dropdown list). Yes, I tried falling back to a previous kernel version - no luck. When I switch to Mint 19, the same dropdown list offers the Digital codec modes, (so, why not just use Mint 19?) but there are other issues I'm having with 19.

Is there a bug here?  Or, is there a way to reinstall USB Audio so that it offers the Digital codec modes once again?  I've even tried compiling and installing the CP210x driver from Silicon Labs and placing it in the appropriate directory - no joy there.  Much thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Please move the solution to an answer. You can answer your own questions.

Comment: I'm new to this forum, Pablo. It's not obvious how to move this to an answer. Provide a hint and I'll be happy to do so.

Comment: Don't worry, nobody born knowing everything. You would have to edit, cut the answer, click on "Answer your own question" and pate the content on the answer: [here](https://i.imgur.com/Cerjwz1.png) is a screenshot/sketch as how should look.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to verify that if Ubuntu is up and running and I plug in the USB cable, only the analog modes are shown in PulseAudio.  However, if I power on the host unit (Icom IC-7100) **FIRST**, then boot the computer into Ubuntu, PulseAudio happily reports both analog AND digital codecs.  This was repeatable.  Sure does explain a lot of configuration issues.